# How to save the last char from a string in C?

Tags: c, unix, posix, rpc

I am trying to save the last char from a string? Any ideas of how to do this?

Goal: I am currently writing a program where one of the tasks are to search for file extensions using Unix / POSIX. For instance, if the user enters:

./r_client localhost -name '*.c'

it should return all files with names .c file extension types. Thus, I am thinking of grabbing the last char strcat it to the following code

and then search through my directory as follows:

below is example code of using regex

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        regex_t regex;
        int reti;
        char msgbuf[100];

        char *name = "*.c";
        // grab last char, strcat it to -> "[a-zA-Z0-9]\.c$" 
        // because it could be '.h', '.x', etc.    

/* Compile regular expression */
        reti = regcomp(&regex, "[a-zA-Z0-9]\.c$", 0);
        if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); exit(1); }

/* Execute regular expression */
        reti = regexec(&regex, "e09s*fdf.ec", 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
        else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
                puts("No match");
        }
        else{
                regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
                exit(1);
        }

/* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
    regfree(&regex);

        return 0;
}
```

// then call ("e09s*fdf.ec" - this is a test) - of how it should fail w/ .c

```
reti = regexec(&regex, "e09s*fdf.ec", 0, NULL, 0);
```

will be replaced with:  dir_entry->d_name

unless there is better way to do this?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Do you want to support shell globs for the file names? If that is what you want to do, use `glob()` or `wordexp()`. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char dest[255];

char get_last_char(char* s)
{
        return s[strlen(s) - 1];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char c = get_last_char(argv[1]);
        char s[2];
        s[0] = c;
        s[1] = '\0';

        strcat(dest, "[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.");
        strcat(dest, s);
        strcat(dest, "$");
        printf("%s\n", dest);

        exit(0);
}
```

Examples:

```
$ ./concatenate1 "*.x"
[a-zA-Z0-9]\.x$
$ ./concatenate1 "*.c"
[a-zA-Z0-9]\.c$
$ ./concatenate1 "*.h"
[a-zA-Z0-9]\.h$
```

Also, consider using `snprintf()` instead of multiple `strcat()` if you find it easier in the long run.

**EDIT:**
The following code should do the job. One thing is missing and marked as `TODO` - validation. You can never be sure that user will pass correct data. If your code relies on the fact that there are no more than `x` characters after the dot, check `remaining_chars_count` and do what you think is good.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char *temp = strstr(argv[1], ".");
        if (!temp)
                {
                        printf("No dot found.\n");
                        exit(1);
                }

        unsigned int remaining_chars_count = strlen(argv[1]) - (temp - argv[1]) - 1;

        /* TODO: add validation at this point! */

        size_t output_string_length = remaining_chars_count;

        char output_string[output_string_length];
        unsigned output_string_count = remaining_chars_count;

        size_t i = strlen(argv[1]);
        for (i; i > strlen(argv[1]) - remaining_chars_count; i--)
                {
                        output_string[output_string_count - 1] = argv[1][i - 1];
                        --output_string_count;
                }

        output_string[output_string_length] = '\0';
        printf("OUTPUT: %s\n", output_string);
        exit(0);

}
```

Examples:

```
$ ./dot1 "*1134..a"
OUTPUT: .a
$ ./dot1 abc.a
OUTPUT: a
$ ./dot1 "*a.hx"
OUTPUT: hx
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Any ideas of how to get all the chars preceding a period? For instance, if the file was '*.xyz' how to get all the chars after the period? knowing that three letter extension will be the max